# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: method replacement doesn't work on Xcode4.6.1

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios4, xcode4.6

I have been overriding "dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:" to use this method in iOS4.3.
But this this technique have got a runtime error since I update Xcode(4.6.1)

```
error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file
```

And mysteriously, "presentViewController:animated:completion:" method is working with no probrem...

Here is "UIViewController+Compatibility.h" I used.

```
@implementation UIViewController (Compatibility)

- (void)iOS4_presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    [self presentModalViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag];
    [self performSelector:@selector(callBlock:) withObject:completion afterDelay:(flag ? 0.5 : 0)];
}

- (void)iOS4_dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:flag];
    [self performSelector:@selector(callBlock:) withObject:completion afterDelay:(flag ? 0.5 : 0)];
}

- (void)callBlock:(void (^)(void))block
{
    if (block) {
        block();
    }
}

+ (void)iOS4compatibilize
{
    // presentViewController:animated:completion:
    Method m1 = class_getInstanceMethod(self.class, @selector(iOS4_presentViewController:animated:completion:));
    class_addMethod(self.class, 
                    @selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:), 
                    method_getImplementation(m1), 
                    method_getTypeEncoding(m1));

    // MEMO:
    // This cause a bug.
    // Method m2 = class_getClassMethod(self.class, @selector(iOS4_dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:));
    // Here is the answer.

    // dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
    Method m2 = class_getInstanceMethod(self.class, @selector(iOS4_dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:));
    class_addMethod(self.class,
                    @selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:),
                    method_getImplementation(m2), 
                    method_getTypeEncoding(m2));
}
@end
```

Is anybody got same probrems?

**MEMO: I've tried these things.**

- Clean my pre-complied binaries.
- Re-launch Xcode, or reboot my mac.
- My Xcode is current newest version (version 4.6.1)
- I have written very short sample code (it simply present Modal View, and close), but I got same error.

I have no idea to solve this situation... Please help

Comment: I'm surprised it was working, don't you think `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` releases view controller (maybe not directly) ? I'd be interested to see if the following helps: retain `self` at `iOS4_dismissViewControllerAnimated` and `iOS4_presentViewController`, release at `callBlock`. It's not pretending to be a good solution though.

Comment: @A-Live Thanks for commenting! I found a simple error in my code. I'm using "class_getClassMethod" (I meant "class_getInstanceMethod"), and got nil on m2... Now it works!

Comment: Nice, I didn't notice that as well, please post the solution as an answer (and accept of course) so that the problem is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. (I was using wrong function)

```
+ (void)iOS4compatibilize
{
    // presentViewController:animated:completion:
    Method m1 = class_getInstanceMethod(self.class, @selector(iOS4_presentViewController:animated:completion:));
    class_addMethod(self.class, 
                    @selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:), 
                    method_getImplementation(m1), 
                    method_getTypeEncoding(m1));

    // dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
    Method m2 = class_getInstanceMethod(self.class, @selector(iOS4_dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:));
    class_addMethod(self.class,
                    @selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:),
                    method_getImplementation(m2), 
                    method_getTypeEncoding(m2));
}
```